# how can move scroll bar automatically?

Tags: android

I am using grid view for display images, I want to scroll move automatically, whenever I add another images in gridview, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to read a little bit more :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection(int)

```
ListView.setSelection(position);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

```
ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position).
```

Answer (score 2):

Either call `setSelection()` or use `smoothScrollToPosition()`.

Comment: @i am fresher,so can you give any example code for that,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got result using `GridView.setSelection(GridView.getCount())`,so scroll bar automatically move to last element of Grid View

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimerTask` to do that since `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` takes delay to update the grid or list.
Code is below:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {         
                    nameHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            },500);
//// And in handler::

Handler nameHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            gridView.setSelection(selectorIndex);
                         // OR
            gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(selectorIndex);
            gridView.invalidate();
        }
    } ;
```