# automatic vertical scrolling in Textview in android

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I want to add one large `TextView` with automatic vertical scrolling with pause and restart method and along with I need one `ProgressBar` of this `TextView`.

Comment: It will great if you can tell where you are exactly stuck or which error you are getting.

Comment: i`m Adding Scrollview to xml layout i`m getting very frequent Scrolling BY PostDelayed(new Runnable()) method

Answer (score 1):

For automatic scrollbar check this 
[how can move scroll bar automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661645/how-can-move-scroll-bar-automaticaly)
One random guess : you can get the position of scrollbar and accordingly change value of progress bar.

Comment: Please Suggest Same FOR Large TextView automatic "Vertical Scrolling"

Comment: Use scrollview and put anything you want inside it like large text view. It will add scrollbar to large text view.

Comment: BY Adding ScrollView I`m Geeting Very fast Scrolling that i can not even recognize it ...Please Send Me Some reelevant Code ./...Can It possible BY adding TextView under ListView ....

Answer (score 0):

you can use scorllview in xml layout

Comment: I want Automatic Scrooling Can I ?, if any link is there then please give me ,Thanks a lot

Comment: i think ajinkya is best answer for this